# Laravel 500 error when using with nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I have tried a lot of configuration settings for nginx to work with laravel but none of them do. I keep getting a 500 error on my webpage.

example.com is currently unable to handle this request.

```
server {
    listen   _:80;
    server_name  example.com;

    root "C:\Users\Administrator\Google Drive\projects\laravel";
    index index.php index.html;

    log_not_found off;
    charset utf-8;

    access_log  logs/cdn.example.com-access.log ;

    location ~ /\. {deny all;}

    location ~ \.css {
        add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
    }

    location ~ \.js {
        add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
    }

    location / {
        include mime.types;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9054;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I am pretty brand new to laravel and sort of new to nginx, I have all my laravel files in the document root that I just moved from my http://localhost:8000 development server. How can I make it live and make it work with nginx?

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to be **example.com**?

Comment: Googling "Laravel 500 error code" leads here. One possibility for the cause is also the PHP version. In my case, I have an old server running PHP 5.3 that I tried putting Laravel on.

Answer (score 0):

I can see wrong configuration in your post. You need to properly setup you web server. You should set `public` directory as root directory, set write permissions on a `storage` folder.

So, change this:

```
root "C:\Users\Administrator\Google Drive\projects\laravel";
```

To this:

```
root "C:\Users\Administrator\Google Drive\projects\laravel\public";
```

And restart your web server.

Comment: I've changed it and rebooted nginx, it still throws the 500 error. Although when adding /public to my url it throws a 404 not found nginx page.

Comment: Did you set write permissions on a storage folder? If not go to the root directory and use `chmod -R 777 storage` command (if you're using Linux server). Also, look for error messages in log files, it will help a lot.

Comment: The storage folder has permissions, I still get the same error when visiting just my domain, but when adding /public it shows a 404 not found. No errors in the error log! I am also using Windows R2 server

Comment: Adding `public` to URL is wrong, do not do that. If your logs are empty, change debug to `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file.

Comment: It is already set to true, I am checking my nginx logs am I meant to be checking laravel logs?

Comment: Try to check Laravel logs too. Also, set `APP_ENV=local`

Comment: Its set to that, also logs arent giving me anything.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Can you contact your hosting support, maybe they will be able to help you? If they'll help you, please write here how did you solve the problem.